# Граббер канала telethon Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Есть простой код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 2*****9
api_hash = 'ee****************74'

client = TelegramClient("Resend", api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=-10*********2))
async def normal_handler(event):
    await client.send_message(-10********3, event.message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

После его запуска, я авторизуюсь по номеру телефона, пишет что успешно зареган. И как только код отлавливает сообщение - из всех устройств у меня выходит из аккаунта(соответственно и код тоже перестает работать).

С таким я уже долго мучаюсь, начинал с самого сложного кода, и вылетало при запуске. Уже дошел и до самого просто кода, и все равно вылетает из всех устройств.

Скажу сразу, лимиты на сообщения и т.д я не превышал. Мне уже кажется, что нужно менять номер телефона...

Что вы скажете?